# SaltStack: is it possible to allow only state.apply for minions?

Tags: salt-stack

I know that there is Blackout mode for salt-minions (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/blackout/index.html) but it is configured on a master side. My need is to configure minion to do not run any commands (I mean any commands like `salt '*' test.ping` or `salt '*' file.mkdir "/tmp/foobar"`) from a salt-master and only allow to run `salt '*' state.apply` with local state files.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I discover the codebase of Salt I found that there is solution for my issue there in upstream. I found that they added **minion_blackout** config to grains not only to pillar, so now I can configure that on my minion and allow only `state.apply` in **minion_blackout_whitelist** config.

Comment: If it's in a grain then the minion can just remove it. That is why it was pillar only - because the master controls the pillar.